# How do I move elements of a page, without triggering a repaint?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transforms

I am currently trying to figure out, how I can move elements (to a arbitrary position) on a web page without triggering repaints of the content (and thus missing the 60fps budget).

My approach was, to use `transform: translate(...)`, as the composition will be done on the GPU and shouldn't need any repaints of the content. Still, when I change the transform property, the element will get repainted.

I created an example for this case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        #moving {
            transform: translate(0, 0);
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="moving"></div>
<script>
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#moving').css('transform', 'translate(100px, 100px)');
    }, 2000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My first question would be? Why don't you want to repaint it? You would need a repaint to see the move, right?

Comment: What do you think *repaint* means?

Comment: Repaints introduce significant paint times and I need to move a whole lot of content, thats not changed in any other way.

Comment: @Mics To my understanding, a repaint means, that the element is drawn into a buffer by the browser. This shouldn't be necessary, when changing the position, as the element itself doesn't change.

Comment: It seems to be fixed on browser side. When using CSS-transform, the current version of chrome is only doing a layer composition.

Answer (score 1):

you can use css keyframes for this

**http://jsfiddle.net/9yqWY/**

```
  #moving {
     animation: move 2s infinite;
     -webkit-animation: move 2s infinite;
     width: 100px;
     position:relative;
     height: 100px;
     background-color: red;
 }
 @keyframes move {
     0 {
         transform: translate(0);
         -webkit-transform: translate(0);
         -moz-transform: translate(0);
     }
     50% {
         transform: translate(100px);
         -webkit-transform: translate(100px);
         -moz-transform: translate(100px);
     }
     100% {
         transform: translate(0);
         -webkit-transform: translate(0);
         -moz-transform: translate(0);
     }
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes move {
     0 {
         transform: translate(0);
         -webkit-transform: translate(0);
         -moz-transform: translate(0);
     }
     50% {
         transform: translate(100px);
         -webkit-transform: translate(100px);
         -moz-transform: translate(100px);
     }
     100% {
         transform: translate(0);
         -webkit-transform: translate(0);
         -moz-transform: translate(0);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think I was not completely clear with what I meant. I need to move the content to a user specified position. So there is no way to pre-define keyframes. I tried generating keyframes on the fly, but the moment that I insert the rule, the page gets repainted.

Answer (score 1):

Repaint is not evil. It's a necessary operation to update image on a display. Modern browsers are pretty smart to repaint the smallest required area. In your example, Chrome only needs 0.18 ms to do the job.

[image: Developer Tools screenshot shows repaint]

As operated element became bigger, repaint will take longer, but still reasonable amount of time (in most cases). It *could* became more costly if it is triggered many times in a row (e.g. with JavaScript/jQuery animation).

Comment: Sadly thats just what happens. I miss my 60fps budget, when moving big elements across the screen programatically.

Comment: Are you using a transition or animation? If you don't (e.g. the move is made at once, like in the example) you can afford more than 16ms for it, the delay won't be much noticeable.

Comment: I have two situations: One is a google maps style panning and the second is a animation that is triggered in some special cases. Especially for the panning I would like to not break the 16ms, as there is some other asynchronous things going on, that can further delay frames.

Comment: Do you have an example I can look on?